# How can make the mRecyclerView control fill in the free space?

Tags: android-studio

I use Code A to design UI with constraint layout, the top of the UI is google AD and the bottom of the UI is toolbar.

I hope the RecyclerView control named mRecyclerView fill in all other space, how can I do?

BTW, Code B is generated by Android Studio 3.01 automatically when I drag and drop RecyclerView control to UI. It's a hard code for layout_width and layout_height.

[image]

**Code A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
     />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolBar"
        style="@style/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBackup"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnBackup" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnExit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="396dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code B**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="396dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **RecyclerView** code like below to fill the free space:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayoutToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```